# 54 V to 5 V using LM2576HV

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, linear-regulator, buck-boost

I have a requirement to convert 54 V battery output to 5 V. My battery's positive terminal is grounded. I tried the connection as mentioned in the datasheet which is attached here, but as soon as I connected to my 54 V positive grounded battery the LM2576HV got burnt. Please suggest what should be done.

[image: LM2576 HV connection]

Here is what I have used in the circuit:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the output need to be referenced to the battery ground? If not you can simply ignore the battery grounding and hook positive to Vin and ground to negative. If you need the output to be referenced to battery ground then a buck converter isn't going to work.

Comment: High much current do you need?

Comment: @user1850479 output need not be referenced to battery ground. When I connected positive ground battery to vin it got damaged

Comment: @BruceAbbott my current requirements is 0.5 Amp

Comment: In that case, you can simply build the circuit in Figure 8-3 of the datasheet, which is a buck converter with up to 60V input and 5/12V output.  You have a 48V battery, so you're good to go.

Comment: @user1850479 But in my case battery positive is grounded. So LM2576 gets faulty

Comment: If you want the +5v to be referenced to the battery ground, then you cannot use that buck converter. If you don't care about the battery ground then the battery ground does not matter and you can use that buck converter. If you aren't sure, draw your circuit so we can figure out what you're doing.

Comment: I suggest using an isolated dc/dc converter eg. https://nz.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Cincon/EC4A21-E?qs=sGAEpiMZZMv0DJfhVcWlK0%252BNBIYn4O1Xs0YuCOWF%2FjdskBwPiNyXZQ%3D%3D

Comment: @user1850479 I had not connected tab of lm3576 HV to ground. Can this be the problem it getting burnt?

Comment: It's very hard to help you without knowing what you actually did.

Comment: @user1850479 I have updated the question and also have attached connection diagram with all components used. Plese check.

Comment: That looks correct. Double check that you actually built it like that, that your components were correct for the voltage, and if you had a load try testing without.

Comment: Connections are accurate and I have also connected SR310 schottky diode in reverse bias between pin 2 and Negative terminal. Also No load is connected, I am trying to measure output voltage in multimeter.

Answer (score 0):

The LM2576HV expects the battery's positive terminal on the input and the negative on GND. As such it can't make a voltage higher than the battery's positive terminal.

Try a boost regulator like the LM5001 instead. Feedback is going to be a bit sketchy, you may need to arrange a special feedback circuit.

Measured from -48 V, +5 is 53V - so a boost topology is needed. The tricky part is that the 48 V is probably not 48.0 V but the 5 V probably should be 5.0 V so  you can't just make a 53 V output boost converter; the 5 V needs to be measured against the supply positive
(AKA ground).

Maybe something like this  (modified version of [LM5001 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5001.pdf) figure 20):

[image]

Comment: The datasheet suggest one such case where it boost (-5 to -12 Volt) input to -12 V output. But i need +5 volt

Comment: Tthat's the LM2676 datasheet right?  that part only makes voltages more negative than the positive supply.  to make them more positive you need a boost converter.

Comment: Sorry but could not understand it.

Comment: updated picture

Comment: Though I want to use 2576 only, I will try it as well.

Comment: as I have already explained 2576 won't swing that way,